# Starting a Python subprocess with a disconnected stdin

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm executing a program in Python that seems to explicitly check if `stdin` is being used, and if it does, it results in some undesirable behaviour whereby it outputs some garbage binary that I don't want. I specifically do *not* want the program to "see" any connected stdin for this reason. However, by default, `subprocess.run()` connects to the parent's stdin, and so if the parent process (for example pytest) has a stdin file, the test will fail.

For example say my test is this (`samtools` can be installed using `conda install -c bioconda samtools`):

```py
import subprocess
def test_execute():
    print(subprocess.run(
        ['samtools', 'sort'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        encoding='utf-8'
    ))
```

If I run `pytest test.py -s`, the code works, because `-s` disconnects stdin. However, if I `pytest test.py`, the command outputs some garbage binary which causes the test to fail:

```
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
E       UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

/media/michael/Storage2/miniconda/lib/python3.7/codecs.py:322: UnicodeDecodeError
```

Is there some way of forcing stdin to disconnect, so that regardless of my `pytest` flags, my subprocess will never detect a connected stdin?

---

Edit: from looking at the [source code of my target program](https://github.com/samtools/samtools/blob/b298f2909dcc9aab42d54117d24cb3711cc1d745/bam_sort.c#L2676) (samtools), it seems that it's using `isatty()` to check if it should produce output. So in this case it looks like I need to fool `isatty()`.

Comment: Hum, not sure, but maybe `sys.stdin = None` may work? Or you could `subprocess.run(what_ever, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)`.

Comment: Nope, `None` is the default, which causes `stdin` to be inherited, and `PIPE` opens a new channel for communicating with the process. They both cause `stdin` to be detected by the subprocess.

Comment: this seems relevant https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this specific problem involves fooling the function `isatty()`, since this is what my subprocess is using to determine whether it should output binary or not. Thus, to solve this, I just need to connect `stdin` to a tty:

```py
import subprocess 
import pty # <--------------------------- Added

def test_execute():
    master, slave = pty.openpty() # <---- Added
    print(subprocess.run(
        ['samtools', 'sort'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdin=slave, # <----------------- Added
        encoding='utf-8'
    ))
```

Now `pytest test.py` always succeeds, hooray!

Comment: This tool makes no sense, it fails even with `echo -n "" | samtools sort`. So well, at least this is no actually a `stdin` problem, or even relevant.

Comment: It makes some sense, since the program thinks it needs to start "processing" data and producing output if you pipe anything into it. But if input is coming from a tty, then it doesn't think it needs to process anything.

Comment: It can be handled better, nothing needs to be processed when you pass nothing in right? `""` and `"\n"` cause the same results while some random strings such as `"asdf"` cause errors. This shows that the program knows the input is null, it still processes it. OK, maybe null is really meaningful in this case, although the result looks like garbage.

Comment: This tool's input files are basically tabular (TSVs), and I think it's choosing to interpret the input "" as "a valid table, with no contents". It's the same as how `len([])` in Python is a valid call, but `len()` is not.